# Replace fragments and start actives based on string name instead of list view item position

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview, android-listfragment

Based on my list view, how can I replace the detail container with a particular fragment or start a particular activity based on the name of the string for the item that was selected rather than the position of the item within the list? I'm looking for something like `case string` rather than `case 0`, `case 1`, `case 2`, etc. The code under **inital but incorrect code suggestion** is similar to what I'm looking for but not the right solution. All help would be appreciated.

**strings**

```
<string-array name="continent_names">
    //item 0    <item>@string/africa</item>
    //item 1    <item>@string/asia</item>
    //item 2    <item>@string/europe</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="continent_descriptions">
    //item 0    <item>@string/africa_description</item>
    //item 1    <item>@string/asia_description </item>
    //item 2    <item>@string/europe_description </item>
</string-array>
```

**FragmentWorld.java**

```
    public class FragmentWorld extends ListFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private WorldListAdapter mAdapter;

    public FragmentWorld() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    public static FragmentWorld newInstance() {
        return new FragmentWorld();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_world, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        initialize(view);
        return view;
    }

    List<World> list = new ArrayList<World>();
    private void initialize(View view) {
        String[] items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continent_names);
        String[] itemDescriptions = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continent_descriptions);
        for (int n = 0; n < items.length; n++){
            World world = new World();
            world.setID();
            world.setName(items[n]);
            world.setDescription(itemDescriptions[n]);
            list.add(world);
        }

        mAdapter = new WorldListAdapter(list, getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // get the adapter, then get the name from the adapter at that position
                WorldListAdapter adapter = (WorldListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
                String country = adapter.getItem(position);

                if (mTwoPane) {
                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);

                    Fragment newFragment;
                    if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                    } else {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                    }
                    WorldActivity activity = (WorldActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
                    Intent intent;
                    if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AsiaActivity.class);
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EuropeActivity.class);
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Set up search view
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_world, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.clearAnimation();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

        View close = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        close.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_content_clear);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**WorldListAdapter.java**

```
public class WorldListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<World> mData;
    private List<World> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public WorldListAdapter (List<World> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getName());
        holder.description.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = new ArrayList(mData);
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<World> resultList = new ArrayList<World>();
                for (World str : mData) {
                    if (str.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                mFilteredData.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<World>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**inital but incorrect code suggestion**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                    Fragment newFragment;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                            break;
                        default:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                            break;
                    }
                    WorldActivity activity = (WorldActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
                    Intent intent;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AsiaActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EuropeActivity.class);
                            break;
                        default:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void setItemSelected(View view) {
                View rowView = view;
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099CC"));

                TextView tv0 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }

            public void setItemNormal() {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    TextView tv0 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name));
                    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    TextView tv1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description));
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is get the adapter from the parent, then get the country name from the adapter.

Try this:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // get the adapter, then get the name from the adapter at that position
            WorldListAdapter adapter = (WorldListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            String country = adapter.getItem(position);

            if (mTwoPane) {
                setItemNormal();
                View rowView = view;
                setItemSelected(rowView);

                Fragment newFragment;
                if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                    newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                    newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                    newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                } else {
                    newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                }
                WorldActivity activity = (WorldActivity) view.getContext();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                Intent intent;
                if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AsiaActivity.class);
                } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EuropeActivity.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

You could also do the comparisons using Raghav's suggestion for `switch` statement with strings.

Comment: Forgive me if there are compile errors, I'm useless at coding without an IDE :)

Comment: What about starting an activity when mTwoPane is false? I need that code also please. I know it's `else {...}` where the ellipses are replaced by that code.

Comment: I assumed you'd be able to figure it out, because it was essentially like the code in the first section.  Anyhow, I updated my answer.  Cheers